# How can I control whether JUnit creates an instance of the class whose behaviour is being tested?

Tags: java, junit

I have noticed that JUnit implicitly creates an instance of my test class. I have added my own call to the constructor and this does not prevent the creation of the instance by JUnit; the net result is two instances are created, as shown by the console output below.
I find this puzzling.  Why is this taking place, and how can I control/prevent the creation of the instance by JUnit? A google search "junit implicit object creation" reveals nothing, but I was able to see where the constructor is invoked by debugging the test.  What I don't understand is why this is taking place, when we have a place to do it ourselves, and how to prevent it from taking place.  I am using JUnit 4 in eclipse photon.
Thanks.

```
public class MainTest extends Main {

    static Main m;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setUpBeforeClass");
        m = new Main();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("tearDownAfterClass");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setup");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        assertEquals(8,m.add(3,5));
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
setUpBeforeClass
Main()
Main()
setup
tearDown
tearDownAfterClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testcase extends the class Main which means the constructor is called upon creation of both the MainTest class and the explicit call of `new Main()`
remove the `extends Main` and you'll be good

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!  I will give you the hallowed green tick in a few minutes when I am able.

Comment: And don't make the m field static. It could be private. And have a name that says its purpose, like *underTest* for example.